# How to create a photoshop script to divide a layer into a grid of separate layers

Tags: grid, photoshop, slice, divide

I have been looking for a solution but I don't think this is possible without writing a script. What I want to do is take a single photoshop layer and divide it into a grid of squares where each square is a separate layer (e.g. a 100px by 100px image broken into 100 10px by 10px squares, each a separate layer).

I know that I can slice the image into a grid and export each square as a separate image, but I want each square to maintain it's position so when all the layers are visible it forms the original image seamlessly (like a bunch of square puzzle pieces).

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone responded in the SuperUser forum and wrote me a really nice script. Does exactly what I need it to do and it scales perfectly for differently sized squares and differently sized documents.

https://superuser.com/questions/425811/is-it-possible-in-photoshop-to-convert-slices-into-photoshop-layers

Answer (score 1):

1. I think this is what you are looking for: [Tile cutter script](http://www.bram.us/2012/04/23/photoshop-google-maps-tile-cutter-script/)
2. You could then import all the tiles stacked into a new image: [Great Tutorial](http://digidelights.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/load-files-into-stack-quick-ps-tutorial.html)
3. With all your tiles stacked in layers you can run: [Layered -> Grid script](http://www.personal.psu.edu/zez1/blogs/my_blog/2011/05/scripts-4-photoshop-file-sequence-to-layers-to-sprite-sheet.html)

The trick is merging 1 and 3

Comment: Thanks for the response. The script you sent does a great job of cutting an image up into tiles, but the result is the same problem as if I exported a grid of slices. I have a folder with the image broken up into squares, but the problem is reassembling them to make the original image again. When I use the Load Files Into Stack script I just get a layered file the size of one of the squares with all the layers stacked on top of each other instead of a file the size of the original image with all the squares tiled together to resemble the original picture.

Comment: You can define a selection using an array of coordinate points like this `var bounds = [[75,75],[125,75],[125,125],[75,125]];` that is the same as the slice you are taking, then `app.activeDocument.selection.select(bounds)` to make the selection, then `app.activeDocument.paste(true)` (true refers to whether you want to paste into the current selection) to paste the tile into it's matching selection. Rinse and repeat.